# Change naming of model_attributes for just model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I have an API and I want the user to be able to send requests that support nested attributes.

Right now, if a user sends the following JSON, it creates the resource correctly.

```
{"name": "John", {"pages_attributes": [{"url":"test"}]}}
```

However, I want to let the user to write pages instead of pages_attributes:

```
{"name": "John", {"pages": [{"url":"test"}]}}
```

Anyway to change the nested attributes to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would be to just modify the hash, like this:

```
params["pages_attributes"] = params.delete("pages")
```

You could put that in a `before_action` to ensure it happens for all the actions in the specific controller.